# Highcharts stacked column with another column overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get highcharts to show a stacked column with another separate (slightly opaque) column overlayed on top of it.

The jsfiddle I am working with can be seen below, basically I want the 'female' stack to overlap/overlay the male stack instead of being adjacent to it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 2],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Janet',
    data: [3, 1, 4, 4, 3],
    stack: 'female',
    stacking:null ,
    color: 'rgba(211, 211, 221, 0.70)' ,
      pointWidth: 50
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adwt7br0/1/

Comment: Look this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement)

Comment: You need to set plotOptions.column.grouping = false

Comment: haha, I had that without using the 'stack' option. Sorry to waste your time, if you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it.